# debugging assignments to global variables before main

Tags: c++, gdb, global-variables, program-entry-point

I'm trying to use gdb to debug a `CPP` application that **crashes before it reaches main**, during **evaluation of expressions assigned to global variables**. Here is a minimal example that demonstrates what I mean:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int f()
{
    int i=7;
    if (rand() > 30) { return i / (i*i-14*i+49); }
    else             { return 6 / (i*i-14*i+49); }
}
int a = f();
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

It contains an illegal division by zero which will trigger an arithmetic exception. I compiled it as usual with

```
$ g++ -ggdb main.cpp -o main
```

Then tried to debug it like this:

```
$ gdb ./main
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000555555554689 in f () at main.cpp:5
5       if (rand() > 30) { return i / (i*i-14*i+49); }
```

My question is: **How can one debug expression evaluations that occur before main**?

Comment: The same way as exceptions that occur after main, put a breakpoint before running.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `f`?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are considering your debugging session a failure.

Comment: Actually my real code contains many (many) global variables, **in multiple files**. Is there a way I can know their order of evaluation?

Comment: What is your target?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom The order of initialisation of objects with static storage duration across translation units is unspecified. If you have any dependencies between translation units, you should write your code so that it forces the correct order. Also, you should avoid global variables. If you have many, that's too many.

Comment: AFAIK, gdb "intercepts" unhandled exceptions and should show you where it happened with simple `bt`.

Comment: I recommend this talk by Matt Godbolt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOfucXtyEsU (slides [here](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2018/blob/master/Presentations/the_bits_between_the_bits/the_bits_between_the_bits__matt_godbolt__cppcon_2018.pdf)) - it gives you the background info to understand how this initialization is done behind the scenes and where you can thus intercept it. In your example, you can [see](https://godbolt.org/z/PMRLWc) that gcc outputs a function that the linker is supposed to call before `main`: `_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z1fv`

Comment: @sklott thanks! the `bt` works great in this context. gdb prints the exact order of global evaluations. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right about the dependencies assumption. the expressions were indeed dependent and I missed that. lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

> How can one debug expression evaluations that occur before main?

There is *nothing* special about `main`. To debug this, your can use either `break f` and `run`, or `istart`, `break f`, `continue`.

On Linux, you should take a look at [rr](https://rr-project.org/), which would allow you to "go back in time" to just before the crash -- it's exceedingly nice.